# The installer needs to commit changes to partition tables, but cannot do so because partitions could not be unmounted. /cdrom

Tags: system-installation, 11.04, ubiquity, unetbootin

I have tried several times to install Natty on its own partition on my laptop (WinXP, Intel x86) using UNetBootin, but it always fail.

There is a dialog box:

```
Failed to unmount partitions

The installer needs to commit changes to partition tables,
but cannot do so because partitions on the following could
not be unmounted.

/cdrom

Please close any applications using these mount points.

Would you like the installer to try to unmount these partitions again?
```

If I click on "continue" Ubiquity will hang up, that is, the slideshow will play forever. I do not have a built-in optical drive and I'm not currently using any peripheral.

I have tried `sudo umount /cdrom` it says that `cdrom` is busy. Then the command `fuser /cdrom` returns "Stale NFS file handle".

How can I work around this to install Ubuntu?

Comment: can you add a link to a screenshot showing the error?

Comment: I have tried but I can no longer open my browser once the install procedure has started, and everything I save is lost when I return to XP...

Comment: Are you able to install using another method?

Comment: Very similar question on superuser. My answer, I believe, may help. http://superuser.com/questions/152490/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-server-10-04-from-a-usb-drive/309145#309145

Comment: Not really... But it's ok now. Thank you all for your help! And, euh, sorry for not responding for so long, my laptop didn't work anymore.

Comment: @Petriborg I was not trying to install Ubuntu from a USB device, but I used UNetBootin to make what they call a "frugal install" on my disk. Then the bug appears when Ubiquity tries to permanently install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in Ubiquity:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1237721&highlight=the+installer+needs+to+commit+changes
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/313452

I eventually found those threads after a long, really non-trivial search... Interesting workarounds are listed there. However I won't vouch for them (see comment). Be careful if you need install Ubuntu from an ISO image directly from your disk!

Comment: I tried one of the suggested workaround but it didn't work for me. Maybe I didn't performed it correctly? Anyway, Ubiquity did not freeze this time, but simply crashed. Subsequently I could no longer start my laptop. Visibly the crash had introduced an error in the config of the bootloader (GRUB). This time I *really* had to get a CD drive.

Answer (score 5):

I have also spent hours trying to fix this, even though my problem did not start with UNetBootin. However I got the same result: the installer just quit and said that thing about not being able to unmount /cdrom

Finally the right solution was found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux

Specifically, do this:

> Note2: Instead of using 'workaround', an alternative is to modify the file /etc/mtab by erasing the line that specifies the partition where the cdrom is mounted. This way the kernel thinks thats the /cdrom is not mounted and will not show the advice when installing ubuntu. I think this procedure is less dangerous than the one in the previus note.

Do this before you start the installer. If that does not work, try to do this right before you press the "Install Now" button.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this when I have to install Ubuntu again...

Comment: This worked for me Cray, thank you! I know this isn't stackexchange etiquette but this problem has been driving me nuts!

Comment: This fix still applies to 12.04. Thanks a million.

Comment: This seems to _still_ appliy to 14.04 and 15.05. But even with out this error I'm getting other errors when installing.

Answer (score 2):

For me

```
sudo umount -l -r -f /cdrom
```

worked like a charm

Comment: This worked perfectly. This should be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue with both unebootin and rufus. I fixed this by turning on `USB 3.0 legacy mode` or `usb3.0 configuration in pre-os` in BIOS.